# Comparing CLOB data types in SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, compare, clob

I have table which have a column of datatype like CLOB.
create table t (
c1 clob
);
The data inserted is in Key Value pair like below
insert into t values ([{"overallOutcome1":"Suitable","checklistVersion":null}]);
insert into t values ([{"overallOutcome1":"Suitable","checklistVersion":1}]);

How can I compare different keys values of the column c1 and get new and old values of
checklistVersion

I used pre-defined function dbms_lob.compare to compare, but this inbuilt-function only gives result as per whether they are equal or no, but it doesn't compare key value pairs.

Comment: Are all you lobs JSON formatted? If so, tell the DB they are json (e.g. using a check constraint "check (c1 is json)" and then use the json functions to get the key/values pairs and compare them.

Comment: what is the json functions to get the key/values pairs and compare them

Comment: Here's a link to the [JSON query part of the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/query-json-data.html#GUID-119E5069-77F2-45DC-B6F0-A1B312945590)

Comment: create table t ( c1 clob check (c1 is json ));

insert into t values ('[{"overallOutcome1":"Suitable","checklistVersion":null}]'); 

select t.c1.[0] from t; --> this select command gives an error. Can you please let me know how to access value for key overallOutcome1.

Comment: select t.c1.overallOutcome1 from t

Comment: You'd be much better off not storing structured data in a CLOB. Split these out into a separate table of two columns and relate it to your primary table with a join key. That way, you can use normal SQL to query it, compare, etc..

Comment: @RiyaJain - this is one of the slightly odd situations where you need to alias the table, even if the alias is the same as the table name - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uRDxVVEd).

Comment: suppose I have table having three column, number, varchar2, clob. Two record looks like below: row1 --> (2195156, 'CARES-RDSCAS99971'[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]) 
row2 --> (2195156, 'CARES-RDSCAS99971'[{"key1":"value5","key2":"value2"}]) using dbms_lob.compare we can compare whether clob column value is equal or no. but I want to compare the data inside clob column